# how to decode json from server in dart?

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, postman

I want to decode a json which is coming back from server when the statuscode was 200 and initialize them to a variable, but i don't know how to do that.

here is my request codes to server:

```
_SendInquiryReq({
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var tok = prefs.getString('tok');

    var Num = NumberController.text;

    var headers = {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $tok',
      'Cookie':
          '.AspNetCore.Session = some thing'
    };

    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'GET', Uri.parse('my Link/$Num'));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
      print("Ok");
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How's the response looks like

Comment: it contains some thing like this: `{                                                                                         "id": "c137c733-2dd9-4ee5-9469-107388e5f4ab",                                                                
   }` i want to decode this "id"

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a class that map your JSON to Class Instance like this:

```
class IdModel {
  String id;

  IdModel({this.id});

  IdModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Now Whenever you are getting the raw JSON response just use the class like this :

```
IdModel model = IdModel.fromJson(yourJson);
```

Use the `model` to get an id!

Answer (score 0):

- First, you have to wait for a response to finish receiving by using `await`
- Proceed with `jsonDecode` or `json.decode` method to decode into map
- You can access your data like `decodedMap['id']`

`final headers = {'key': 'value'};`
`final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('uri'));`
`request.headers.addAll(headers);`
`final response = await request.send();`
`final reponseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();`
`final decodeMap = json.decode(reponseString);`